# How to make a POST request to a page that may redirect to a login page

Tags: vba, post, outlook, winhttp

I am using a macro in Outlook VBA to submit a file via POST to a URL:

```
Set http = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
http.Open "POST", UrlToPostTo, False    'True                                          '
http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; "
http.Send data
```

My problem is the page that will accept the request (a file upload page, in this case) is protected by authentication - the initial request for it above will return a login page instead of the page itself.

I have tried to detect if the login page appears and if so, post the username and password as form variables (I'm hoping this is equivalent to a human typing said username and password into a page in the web browser).

So the steps are:
* request URL (include file with post).
* Check if the reponse is the login page.
* If so, then in the same http session, submit the username and password to the URL.
* If the server now processes the original post, good, otherwise I can post it again.

The code looks like:

```
' if the login page comes back, send credentials                                     '
If (InStr(http.ResponseText, "j_password") > 0) Then

    Dim loginData As String
    loginData = "j_username=theusername&j_password=thepassword"

    http.Open "POST", UrlToPostTo, False
    http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; "
    http.Send loginData
End If
```

But when I do this, The http.Responsetext is just the login page still (or again?).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Is my plan even valid?

(This is related to trying to solve [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851269/outlook-how-do-i-post-the-selected-message-to-a-web-server-using-vba) )

Answer (score 10):

I know this thread is ancient and I realize the OP most definitely moved on long ago.  I just spent the better part of 3 evenings being humbled by this exact same problem, and this thread kept coming up when I would stop to research more so I thought I would contribute for the next guy who comes along.

The trick is:

- Disable redirects using using the [Option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384108(v=vs.85).aspx) property, to stop it from
  moving on without you. (see comments below)
- Capture the redirect on the output of the [Status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384108(v=vs.85).aspx) property, and
  handle from there.

I'm sure there's other ways, but this seemed pretty elegant to me, and I found lots of other ways to use it.

To use the OPs code example, you could make your request as planned with one exception: The EnableRedirects var, which must come after opening the connection (didn't read that anywhere, just couldn't get it to stick to a closed connection).

Good luck "next guy"!

```
    Dim http As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Dim UrlToPostTo As String, UrlRedirectedTo As String

    'Your initial request (assuming lots here)
    Set http = New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    http.Open "POST", UrlToPostTo, False
    'Stop it from redirecting automatically, so you can capture it
    http.Option(WinHttpRequestOption_EnableRedirects) = False 'You can also use the collection index instead of the pretty name
    http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; "
    http.Send

    'Now if you have an active session, you should get your desired content
    'If it redirected you, you'll have a different status, header etc...    

    If http.status = "302" Then
        Dim loginData As String
        'Now lets find out where we're being pointed and POST there
        'This may not be the same url you see in your address bar 
        UrlRedirectedTo = http.GetResponseHeader("Location")
        'Also, you may have to do this again to arrive back at the intended resource    
        loginData = "j_username=theusername&j_password=thepassword"
        http.Open "POST", UrlRedirectedTo, False
        http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
        http.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; "
        http.Send loginData
    End If
```

Some info I found useful in the MSDN maze.

[WinHttpRequest Options (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384108(v=vs.85).aspx)

[WinHttpRequest Object (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384106(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Cookie Handling WinHttp (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383261(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Is the logon page at the same URL as the page you originally submitted to? I don't see any code that changes `urlToPostTo`

After your first send, you might want to look at the `Status` property of your request. See [the RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) for what each status code means. It could also help to use the `GetAllResponseHeaders` method to work out exactly what's going on. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384106(VS.85).aspx) for more on that

Comment: The logon page URL is the same - I am requesting the original page and it is serving the original page if I am already authenticated, or the login page otherwise. I don't seem to be redirected, the URL in browser doesn't change when you do it manually.

Comment: @barrowc, thanks, I'll try checking the status and headers as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible for you to store the username and password in cookies which would allow you to access your page directly.

```
    Dim doc As WinHttp.WinHttpRequest
    Set doc = New WinHttpRequest

    doc.Open "POST", url, False

    doc.SetRequestHeader "Cookie", "UserID=" & username
    doc.SetRequestHeader "Cookie", "Password=" & password
```

You need to confirm the variable names on your server.  You can use a tool like *ieHTTPHeaders* to inspect the headers when you access the page from the browser to see what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try **SetCredentials** -- it may work for you, e.g.:

```
http.Open "POST", UrlToPostTo, False
http.SetCredentials "YourUsername", "YourPassword", 0
http.Send
```

Source: http://www.automateexcel.com/2005/02/11/excel_vba_winhttprequest_with_login_and/